# cant get breakets to work witch lineinfile

Tags: ansible

for some reason, I can't get `[]` to work with `insertafter` and I really don't know why. it is supposed to work on localhost. if I remove the `[]` in the file and it the play it works but I need the `[]`  running the play gives me An exception that occurred during task execution.

```
---
   - name:
     hosts: localhost
     connection: local 
     tasks:
        - name: test
          lineinfile: dest=./inventories/hosts  state=present line="host" insertafter="[foo]"
```

Comment: i suggest you to do: insertafter='\\[foo\\]' with single quote. without that, its a regex expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to escape the [] chars: use single quote or you have to duplicate \ with double quote

```
- name: test
  lineinfile: 
    dest: ./inventories/hosts  
    state: present 
    line: "host" 
    insertafter: '\[foo\]'  # or "\\[foo\\]"
```